# How to determine what observable been changed in Observable.merge?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Below you can see my code that I have simplified for readability and clarity:

```
connect(): Observable<Customer[]> {
   const displayDataChanges = [
     this._customerDatabase.dataChange,
     this._filterChange,
     this._sort.mdSortChange,
     this._paginator.page
   ];
   return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
     let data = this._customerDatabase.data.slice();
     data = this.getFilteredData(data);
     data = this.getSortedData(data);
     const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
     return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
   });
}
```

This method will return an Observable array of Customers.

The part below defines an array of Observables:

```
const displayDataChanges = [
      this._customerDatabase.dataChange,
      this._filterChange,
      this._sort.mdSortChange,
      this._paginator.page
];
```

Every time one of these emit data I expect my Array of Customers to change. (when i load the data, when my filter has changed, when i choose another sort mechanism and when i change the page)

I then Merge all of these together so that i can 'assemble' my data that has to be returned. As you can see, it is not very performant because it doesn't distinguish between what actual observable has emitted data...

**How do I accomplish this and determine which observable has been changed?**
*(Pseudo code below)*

```
return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {

 **[ALWAYS]**
 let data = this._customerDatabase.data.slice();

 **[IF MY SORTING HAS CHANGED]**
 data = this.getSortedData(data); /* After which i will change the dataSet */
 **[IF MY FILTER HAS CHANGED]**
 data = this.getFilteredData(data);

 **[ALWAYS]**
 const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
 return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do this is to make your Observables emit an object that has a type. For example:

```
connect(): Observable<Customer[]> {

   const typifier = (type) => {
       return (val) => {
           return { type: type, value: val };
       }
   };

   const displayDataChanges = [
       this._customerDatabase.dataChange,
       this._filterChange.pipe(map(typifier('filterChange'))),
       this._sort.mdSortChange.pipe(map(typifier('sortChange'))),
       this._paginator.page
   ];

   return merge(...displayDataChanges).pipe(map(obj => {

       let data = this._customerDatabase.data.slice();

       if (obj.type === 'filterChange')
       {
           data = this.getFilteredData(data);
       }

       if (obj.type === 'sortChange')
       {
           data = this.getSortedData(data);
       }

       const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
       return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
   }));
}
```

Here is a link to a [code snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rmbhsh) that you can play with that uses click and interval observables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combineLatest` instead of `merge`. That way, you can grab an emitted value for each of your merged observables. All you have to do is to keep a reference of the last value of `mdSortChange` and `_filterChange` to check if they have changed.

[CombineLatest documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md)

```
connect(): Observable<Customer[]> {
  const displayDataChanges = [
    this._customerDatabase.dataChange,
    this._filterChange,
    this._sort.mdSortChange,
    this._paginator.page
  ];

  let lastFilter = null;
  let lastSort= null;

  return Observable
    .combineLatest(...displayDataChanges)
    .map(([newData, newFilter, newSort, newPage]) => {
      let data = this._customerDatabase.data.slice();

      if (newFilter !== lastFilter) {
        data = this.getFilteredData(data);
        lastFilter = newFilter ;
      }

      if (newSort !== lastSort) {
        data = this.getSortedData(data);
        lastSort = newSort;
      }

      const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thank you for answering! I have tried that but it doesn't seem to be executing the code inside the Observable?

Comment: With merge it does but then again, that was my problem ;)

Comment: Each `displayDataChanges` should emit at least one value. Can you ty changing page, filters and sorting to see if this is working ?

Comment: `combineLatest` only emits when all combined observables have emitted a least one value. Resulting observable emits an array containing the last emited value of each combined observables.
`merge` emits whenever a merged observable emit. Resulting observable emit a single value (not an array).