# How to combine 2 or more observables so that you know which emitted?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

let's say you have 2 observables:

```
const obs1$: Observable<string[]> = this.getObs1$();
const obs2$: Observable<string[]> = this.getObs2$();
```

i want to combine these 2 so that in subscription (or rxjs map) i know which emitted the values. I can't use combineLatest because for the other observable i just get the latest value it emitted at some point.

Comment: Can't you add type for each observable? Something like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455763/how-to-determine-what-observable-been-changed-in-observable-merge

Comment: You can chain each Observable with `map()` and wrap it with some data strucutre that you can use to identify the source.

Comment: this is what i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a purely RxJS solution to this (but hopefully someone can prove me wrong on that!)

You could use a variable in the outter scope to track the emitting observable as a workaround

```js
let trigger: TriggerEnum;

const obs1$: Observable<string[]> = this.getObs1$()
  .pipe(tap(() => trigger = TriggerEnum.One));
const obs2$: Observable<string[]> = this.getObs2$()
  .pipe(tap(() => trigger = TriggerEnum.Two));;

combineLatest(....).subscribe(
 // check trigger value
);
```

From the docs as a just-in-case: be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value

Comment: i had time to fast see this before a trip i left so i remembered this wrong. i added value to return value with map. this is better than what i did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) to combine the two observables into a single observable.  Then, do what @martin suggested and map each source's emissions to a little structure that allows you identify the source:

```js
const obs1$: Observable<number[]> = getNumbers();
const obs2$: Observable<string[]> = getLetters();

const combined$ = merge(
  obs1$.pipe(map(data => ({ source: 'obs1$', data }))), 
  obs2$.pipe(map(data => ({ source: 'obs2$', data })))
);

combined$.subscribe(
   ({ source, data }) => console.log(`[${source}] data: ${data}`)
);

// OUTPUT:
//
// [obs1$] data: 1
// [obs2$] data: A
// [obs2$] data: A,B
// [obs2$] data: A,B,C
// [obs1$] data: 1,2
// [obs2$] data: A,B,C,D
...
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70903124?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) example.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what I needed out of `merge` but my go-to is `combineLatestWith`

```
this.transaction$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe), 
  combineLatestWith(this.selectedStatus$)) // ngxs add latest sliced data to response
  .subscribe(([status, tx]) => {
    console.log(status, tx);
  });
```

With NGXS its convenient to attach one of your slices via selector to also get the data in the response.