# Create an observable depending on which observable emitted last

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to combine 2 observables, take the latest value of each of them (`combineLatest`) and apply a different function depending on which was the latest emitted observable. Something like this:

```
public obs1: BehaviorSubject<int> = ...;
public obs2: Observable<string> = ...;

(...)

this.desiredObservable = combineLatest([this.obs1, this.obs2],
  (myInt, myString) => {
    if (this.obs1 was the latest to emit) {
        return func1(myInt, myString);
    }  else {
        return func2(myInt, myString);
    }
});
```

I found [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903124/how-to-combine-2-or-more-observables-so-that-you-know-which-emitted), but I wonder if there is a simpler way.

Comment: You could use `timestamp()` operator for each source Observable that will wrap each `next` with an object that contains timestamp when the value was received by the operator.

Comment: Can't you use `this.obs1.value`? Or `combineLatest([this.obs1.pipe(take(1)), this.obs2]).subscribe...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`timestamp` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timestamp) is the way to go fo this :

```
import { combineLatest, timer, timestamp } from 'rxjs';

const obs1$ = timer(0, 100).pipe(timestamp());
const obs2$ = timer(0, 10).pipe(timestamp());

const obs$ = combineLatest([obs1$, obs2$], (ts1, ts2) => {
  if (ts1.timestamp > ts2.timestamp) {
    ts1.value; // obs1$ is more recent
  } else {
    ts2.value; // obs2$ is more recent
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that way to use `timestamp`. Great!